# Can't inizialitize git hub repository on VsCode

Tags: html, github, visual-studio-code

Well I’ve been trying for a long time to initialize a repository on VsCode (i’m following a HTML5 & CSS course by Mosh). Every time i try press **initialize repository** button it does nothing, i can’t “press it” (it’s like is enabled), it just doesn’t seem to work … Already created a Git Hub acc, installed Git Hub for desktop, went to “git hub” extension on VsCode to try to initilize it… but it doesn’t work

I have no idea what to do.
Grateful to hear your tips

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R26W.png)

Answer (score -1):

Your OS does not have Git installed yet. As in your image, click Download Git for Windows button or download it from the main website: https://git-scm.com/downloads